# Show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times S^{1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times S^{1}$

Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^2$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times S^{1}$ then these implies that
$\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times S^{1}$ and therefore $H_1(\mathbb{R} \times S^1) \cong H_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ but $H_1(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S^1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(\mathbb{R}^2)=\{0\}$ and how $H_1(\mathbb{R} \times S^1) \cong H_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ then $\mathbb{Z} \cong 0$ but clearly that is a contradiction.

My question is using tools of differential topology how could I demonstrate this fact?
Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: A slightly different approach: Note that $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ which not even homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d} \newcommand{\dx}{\d \!}$
I will just reformulate a bit your argument.
This way, you will not have to show that $H_1(X\times Y) \simeq H_1(X)\oplus H_1(Y)$.
Consider the one form $\dx \theta$ on $\Bbb R \times S^1$.
Define a loop $\gamma \colon [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb R\times S^1$ by $\gamma(t) = (0, e^{it})$.
Then
$$
\int_{\gamma}\dx \theta = 2\pi \neq 0.
$$
Since $\dx\theta$ is closed, it follows that it defines a cohomology class $[\dx \theta] \neq 0$, and in particular, $H_1(\Bbb R\times S^1) \neq 0$.
But $H_1(\Bbb R^2) = 0$.
Since the cohomology is invariant under diffeomorphism, these two spaces cannot be diffeomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

One shows in calculus that every closed 1-form on R^2 is exact — and thus its integral along a closed curve is zero.

On the other hand, you can easily find a 1-form on the cylinder and a curve such that the integral is non-zero.

Since the vanishing of integrals of closed forms along closed curves is invariant under diffeomorphism...